# Can I use the wordpress loop in pages?

Tags: pages

I'm making my first Wordpress theme and I've faced an issue lately.

I have a template file `page-event.php`. I intend to use it to answer the `/events` path (I have also created an events page). This works at the moment, but I want to make the events template loop through all the posts in categories `events`.

For some reason, this doesn't work. When I use the loop in the `page-event.php` template, it brings up only one post named `events`. I don't know why this happens.

I think it's showing just the category holder for events.

My question is

- Isn't it possible to use the Wordpress loop to loop posts in any template 
  file?
- Why does the code loop through categories instead of posts?

Here's a look through my code in my `page-events.php`

```
<?php get_header();?>

<?php 
    if(have_posts()){
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();?>
            <p><?php the_title();?></p>
        <?php }
    } 

    wp_reset_query();
    ?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

I expect this code to at least provide a simple list of all the posts on the blog, but it returns a single category with the name `events`.

Thanks in advance.

Update.

I recently echoed out the `$query_string` variable to see what Wordpress was doing, it returned `pagename=events`. So it turns out Wordpress is only searching for pages because the `page-event.php` was a post type of page.

Need more help on how to make the loop search for posts instead of pages.

Comment: Hi, could you show us your current code? It will be easier to find error then, I guess :) And by the way... Why do you want to use page for displaying events and not just use a category or custom post type?

Comment: Thank you Krzysiek. I've added a little code block to show the problem. And concerning your question, that was exactly what I wanted to do; make a custom post type event. But I learned that the user will lose all those post types when they change to another theme. I didn't want that to happen, so I thought of still keeping everything as blog posts but differentiating with the categories options.

Comment: You can perform new queries with `WP_Query` outside of this template's loop code. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: I took out time to look into it Mike and It solved my problem. I still have questions Mike, please explain why the solution on that page worked.